# More than one AnimationDrawable at the same time

Tags: android, animation, drawable

I would like to start different animations at the same time when the app starts. I added my code in the onWindowFocusChanged function for one animated button and I haven't problems. However, when I try to animate another button, the second one don't move, fixed on the first frame.
Anyone knows how can I get over?

Some piece of code:

In the OnCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      Button mButtonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlay);
      mButtonPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_play);      
      buttonAnimationPlay = (AnimationDrawable)mButtonPlay.getBackground();
      Button mButtonOptions = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonOptions);
      mButtonOptions.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_options);
      buttonAnimationOptions = (AnimationDrawable)mButtonPlay.getBackground();
  }
enter code here
```

And in the onWindowFocusChanged :

```
@Override
  public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
  {
      if (hasFocus)
      {
    buttonAnimationPlay.start();  
    buttonAnimationOptions.start();  
      }
      else
      {   
    buttonAnimationPlay.stop();  
    buttonAnimationOptions.stop();  
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it finally! There were a mistake in the code, what a crap! This is the good one:

```
  final Button mButtonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlay);
  mButtonPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_play);
  buttonAnimationPlay = (AnimationDrawable)mButtonPlay.getBackground();


  final Button mButtonOptions = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonOptions);
  mButtonOptions.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_play);
  buttonAnimationOptions = (AnimationDrawable)mButtonOptions.getBackground();
```

Anyway, I've also tried the programmatically add of views and, now, it also works. For anyone would use one or the other kind, this is the other one:

```
RelativeLayout Relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeForButtons);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParamsPlay = 
      new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParamsOptions = 
      new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  relativeParamsPlay.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.Title);
  relativeParamsPlay.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
  final Button mButtonPlay = new Button(this);
  mButtonPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_play);
  buttonAnimationPlay = (AnimationDrawable)mButtonPlay.getBackground();
  mButtonPlay.setId(1);
  mButtonPlay.setText("PLAY");
  Relative.addView(mButtonPlay,relativeParamsPlay);   

  final Button mButtonOptions = new Button(this);
  mButtonOptions.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_options);
  buttonAnimationOptions = (AnimationDrawable)mButtonOptions.getBackground();
  mButtonOptions.setId(2);
  mButtonOptions.setText("OPTIONS");
  relativeParamsOptions.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mButtonPlay.getId());
  relativeParamsOptions.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
  Relative.addView(mButtonOptions,relativeParamsOptions);
```

All of that is in the OnCreate function. If you want to start animations, use the onWindowFocusChanged function as explained above.

Hope it helps! :)